# Python flassger: Get query with extended conditions ? (more, less, between...)

Tags: python, swagger, flask-sqlalchemy, swagger-ui, flask-restful

I develop a python application based on flask that connects to a postgresql database and exposes the API using flassger (swagger UI).
I already defined a basic API (handle entries by ID, etc) as well a a query api to match different parameters (name=='John Doe'for example).

**I would like to expand this query api to integrate more complex queries such as lower than, higher than, between, contains, etc.**

I search on internet but couldn't find a proper way to do it. **Any suggestion ?**

I found this article which was useful but does not say anything about the implementation of the query: https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Here is briefly how it looks like so far (some extracted code):

GET_query.xml:

```
Return an account information
---
tags:
  - accounts
parameters:
  - name: name
    in: query
    type: string
    example: John Doe
  - name: number
    in: query
    type: string
    example: X
  - name: opened
    in: query
    type: boolean
    example: False
  - name: highlighted
    in: query
    type: boolean
    example: False
  - name: date_opened
    in: query
    type: Date
    example: 2018-01-01
```

Blueprint definition:

```
ACCOUNTS_BLUEPRINT = Blueprint('accounts', __name__)

Api(ACCOUNTS_BLUEPRINT).add_resource(
    AccountQueryResource,
    '/accounts/<query>',
    endpoint='accountq'
)

Api(ACCOUNTS_BLUEPRINT).add_resource(
    AccountResource,
    '/accounts/<int:id>',
    endpoint='account'
)

Api(ACCOUNTS_BLUEPRINT).add_resource(
    AccountListResource,
    '/accounts',
    endpoint='accounts'
)
```

Resource:

```
from flasgger import swag_from
from urllib import parse
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_restful.reqparse import Argument
from flask import request as req
...
class AccountQueryResource(Resource):
    """ Verbs relative to the accounts """

    @staticmethod
    @swag_from('../swagger/accounts/GET_query.yml')
    def get(query):
        """ Handle complex queries """
        logger.debug('Recv %s:%s from %s', req.url, req.data, req.remote_addr)
        query = dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(req.url).query))
        logger.debug('Get query: {}'.format(query))
        try:
            account = AccountRepository.filter(**query)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return {'error': '{}'.format(e)}, 409
        if account:
            result = AccountSchema(many=True).dump(account)
            logger.debug('Get query returns: {}({})'.format(account, result))
            return {'account': result}, 200
        logger.debug('Get query returns: {}'.format(account))
        return {'message': 'No account corresponds to {}'.format(query)}, 404
```

And finally the epository:

```
class AccountRepository:
    """ The repository for the account model """

    @staticmethod
    def get(id):
        """ Query an account by ID """
        account = AccountModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        logger.debug('Get ID %d: got:%s', id, account)
        return account

    @staticmethod
    def filter(**kwargs):
        """ Query an account """
        account = AccountModel.query.filter_by(**kwargs).all()
        logger.debug('Filter %s: found:%s', kwargs, account)
        return account
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your exact problem, but I had a problem similar to yours, and I fixed it with:

```
query = []
if location:
    query.append(obj.location==location)
```

I will query this list of queries with

```
obj.query.filter(*query).all()
```

Where in above examples, `obj` is the name of a `model` you have created.

How is this help? this will allow you to fill in the variables you have dynamically and each query has its own conditions. you can use `==`, `!=`, `<=`, etc.

note you should use `filter` and not `filter_by` then you can as many operators as you like.
you can read [link1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) and [link2](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html) for documents on how to query sqlalchemy.

edit:

```
name = request.args.get("name")
address = request.args.get("address")
age = request.args.get("address")
query = []
if name:
    query.append(Myobject.name==name)
if address:
    query.append(Myobject.address==name)
if age:
    query.append(Myobject.age >= age) # look how we select people with age over the provided number!

query_result = Myobject.query.filter(*query).all()
```

`if`'s will help you when there is no value provided by the user. this way you are not including those queries in your main query. with use of `get`, if these values are not provided by the user, they will be None and respected query won't be added to the query list.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. How do you send and split split the query request ?
For example now I send them like:
   "curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/accounts/{query}?name=John%20Doe&number=X&opened=false&highlighted=false&date=2018-01-01" -H  "accept: application/json" "

Do you have an example ? I suppose urllib.parse.parse_qsl would not recognize special characters...

Comment: If you send arguments in the `URL`, you can use `name = request.args.get('name')`. you can put variable names(`name`, `number`, `opened`, `highlighted`, `date`) in `get` function separately and assign it to different variables. it will be `None` if the variable isn't provided in the `URL`. so it's safe to use too.

Comment: But then how do I indicate if I want it to be ==, >=, != and so on ? How do I handle between then for a same argument ?

Comment: look how I have put `location` in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the more detail example. 
I still don't get exactly how to ask for different conditions. For example if I take age in your example above, how would the get request ask for example age between 5 and 10 ? would it be GET ...{query}?age>5&age<10 ? But then I have 2 different age in there which would mean I need all permutations in my query parsing right ?

Comment: Found this really informative page on the format: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/
I'll go from there :) Thanks